# evaluating file inside let

Tags: emacs

If `my-variable` is globally undefined, and `my-file.el` uses it,

```
;; -*-  lexical-binding: t; -*-
(let((my-variable 1))
  (load "/path/to/my-file.el"))
```

reports an error:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable my-variable)
```

On the other hand,

```
;; -*-  lexical-binding: t; -*-
(defvar my-variable 11)
(let((my-variable 1))
  (load "/path/to/my-file.el"))
```

works using locally defined value 1.
Why do I have to use `defvar`?

PS: `my-file.el` can be a one-liner:

```
(1+ my-variable)
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the behaviour. `let` is used to dynamically bind a variable, it creates a new one if it doesn't exist.

Comment: @choroba: try `(if (= my-variable 1) (message "Yes") (message "No"))` as the contents of `my-file.el`.

Comment: It prints `Yes` or `No` according to the value of the variable. What version of Emacs do you use?

Comment: Show code that reproduces the problem. This code does not. You don't show how or where you use `my-variable`. So you're getting answers that are guesses. (They might be correct, but there's no way of knowing from your question as stated.)

Comment: @choroba: I provided my reproducer as a "non-answer answer".

Answer (score 2):

The file that the `let` is in is probably using `lexical-binding`, which means that for:

```el
(let ((my-variable 1))
  (load "/path/to/my-file.el"))
```

There is nothing in the lexical scope of `my-variable` which *uses* it.

If you byte-compiled the file, it would tell you:

> Warning: Unused lexical variable ‘my-variable’

Adding the `defvar` marks it as a dynamic scope variable, in which case the code evaluated while `my-file.el` is being loaded will also see the let-bound value.

Note that `(defvar my-variable)` with no value is also sufficient to do that, and is what you should use if this isn't where the variable is supposed to be *defined*.

Answer (score 1):

See [Using Lexical Binding](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Using-Lexical-Binding.html):

> Lexical binding is also enabled in Lisp Interaction and IELM mode, used in the *scratch* and *ielm* buffers, and also when evaluating expressions via M-: (eval-expression) and when processing the --eval command-line options of Emacs (see Action Arguments in The GNU Emacs Manual) and emacsclient (see emacsclient Options in The GNU Emacs Manual).

So, if you evaluate the `let` in the `*scratch*` buffer, it uses lexical binding, which means the value of the variable is only bound to the lexical context, i.e. it isn't preserved when loading a different file.

Another possibility is you run it from an `.el` file with lexical binding turned on. If you turn it off, it should work the way you expected. Use the buffer local variable `lexical-binding` to enable or disable it.

Comment: Note that the quoted behaviour (lexical binding being used by default in many situations) was only introduced in 27.1.  In previous versions of Emacs, dynamic binding would have been used by default in these situations.

Answer (score 0):

[Not an answer but I did not want to edit the OP's question willy-nilly with what *I* see (and it's too long for a comment). I just provide a description of how I reproduce the problem since @choroba seems to get different results]

I have this in `/tmp/my-file.el`:

```el
(if (= my-variable 1) (message "Yes") (message "No"))
```

I start emacs with `emacs -Q` and evaluate the following in the `*scratch*` buffer (sneaking in the version info):

```el
(emacs-version '(4))
GNU Emacs 28.0.50 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.25, cairo version 1.16.0)
 of 2021-03-07nil

(let ((my-variable 1))
  (message (format "%d" my-variable))
  (load "/tmp/foo.el"))
```

and I get the following backtrace:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable my-variable)
  (= my-variable 1)
  (if (= my-variable 1) (message "Yes") (message "No"))
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/tmp/foo.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 54
  load-with-code-conversion("/tmp/foo.el" "/tmp/foo.el" nil nil)
  load("/tmp/foo.el")
  (let ((my-variable 1)) (message (format "%d" my-variable)) (load "/tmp/foo.el"))
  (progn (let ((my-variable 1)) (message (format "%d" my-variable)) (load "/tmp/foo.el")))
  eval((progn (let ((my-variable 1)) (message (format "%d" my-variable)) (load "/tmp/foo.el"))) t)
  elisp--eval-last-sexp(t)
  eval-last-sexp(t)
  eval-print-last-sexp(nil)
  funcall-interactively(eval-print-last-sexp nil)
  call-interactively(eval-print-last-sexp nil nil)
  command-execute(eval-print-last-sexp)
```

I get exactly the same result with the emacs that is packaged in my distro (Fedora 33): `GNU Emacs 27.1 (build 1, x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.22, cairo version 1.16.0) of 2020-08-20`.

Comment: Fixed - I hope. But I also hope the OP will actually update his question with what he did exactly, and I can delete the whole "non-answer answer".